# pass methods to razor pages textArea declaration for calculating "readonly" dinamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to pass a method into a `textArea` declaration (to calculate if the `textArea` should be `readOnly` or not)

I'm getting:

> The tag helper 'textarea' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.

I have something like this in my cshtml file:

```html
<td>
    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments!.PALaborComment" rows="1" @SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA" )>
    </textarea>
</td>
```

and the .cs file:

```cs
private string SetTextAreaVisibility(string ManagerType, string textboxType)
{
    if (ManagerType == "_PAExpenditureLayout" && textboxType == "PA") 
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return "readonly";
    }
}
```

This is a shortened version as I want a bit more logic into the method, but the idea would be to pass this method: `SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA" )` into the texArea declaration so it can calculate wether it should put a "readonly" tag or not (to make editable the `textArea` or not.
the cshtml page has several text areas, and depending a status, user, etc will be editable or not.

If you have another suggestion of how can I do this I'm also happy to hear about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML there is an attribute specifically made for readonly inputs.

So in your case, you will change the return type of the method to **bool** and then bind it to the value of **readonly** attribute in the textarea.

Here is a working example:

HTML/cshtml:

```html
<td>
    <textarea class="form-control"
              asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments!.PALaborComment"
              rows="1"
              readonly="@SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA")"> 
    </textarea>
</td>
```

c# method:

```cs
private bool SetTextAreaVisibility(string ManagerType, string textboxType)
{
    if (ManagerType == "_PAExpenditureLayout" && textboxType == "PA")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MDN Docs for readonly attribute: [readonly docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#readonly)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, the readonly="@SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA")"  method doesn't get recognized, as per other comment it seems methods can't be passed to razor pages textArea

Comment: The purpose of the MVC pattern is to separate logic as much as possible. For instance, the controller should only manage data and perform operations and send a response back to the view. So you either add this method to the razor page or send the value of the method to the razor page using the corresponding controller.

Comment: oh, actually this has worked, I noticed that if I put the method call as the first parameter in the textArea element it works well :)

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass methods to razor pages textArea,but you can pass the result of SetTextAreaVisibility to razor page with model,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class TestModel {
        public string ManagerType { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

    }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
            var model = new TestModel {  ManagerType= "_PAExpenditureLayout" };

            model.status = SetTextAreaVisibility(model.ManagerType, "PA");
            return View(model);
        }
```

view:

```
<td><textarea class="form-control" asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments!.PALaborComment" rows="1" @SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA" )></textarea></td>
    @section Scripts{ 
        <script>
        $(function () {
            if ("@Model.status"== "readonly") {
                $('textarea').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("readonly", true);
                });
            }
            
        })
        </script>
    
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would work for several text areas, I should have to declare  the script in each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that you can write a custom tag helper.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace CustomTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "is-readonly")]
    public class ReadonlyTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool IsReadonly { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (IsReadonly)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either Register the TagHelpers to _ViewImports.cshtml for global use

```
@addTagHelper CustomTagHelpers.*, TagHelpers
```

Or import at the top of the page to use

```
@using CustomTagHelpers.TagHelpers
```

```cs
<textarea class="form-control"
          asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments!.PALaborComment"
          rows="1"
          is-readonly="@SetTextAreaVisibility(@Model.ManagerType, "PA")"> 
</textarea>
```

---

**Reference**

[Condition Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-6.0#condition-tag-helper)

[Custom Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-custom-tag-helpers/)

Comment: this is a really complete solution, I'm sure it will solve the issue, however a simpler one for my case was the one from @mohammed